# Existing file nonexistent?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-hosting

On a website I'm building, I have a png file that appears on the website many times. Everything works fine on my computer, but when I put it on Apache, everything loads but the image. I've deleted every file on the server and reuploaded everything, and it still doesn't work. I've confirmed it works locally before and after reuploading it. What could be going wrong?

Comment: Have you looked into the permissions on the image itself?

Comment: @JohnK it's 777 rwxrwxrwx on my machine, but for some reason every file on the server is rw-r--r--, except this one, which became rw-------. Weird, but it's fixed.

Comment: That is strange.  What method do you use to copy the files over?  That'd be my top guess for the culprit.  Glad to know its working!

Comment: If the issue is fixed, please put the "fix" as an answer and accept it, or just delete this question. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnK I use SFTP. The problem image is the only file from the internet, but if I take any other image and download it, it's rw-r--r--

Comment: Ah gotchya. @MarkStosberg will do

Comment: @Mark, we don't delete question from this site when they're solved. We leave them so others with the same problem can find them. Nor do we edit the title. Please take a few moments to familiarise yourself with the site before making any more such comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend double checking the permissions - seems like that would be the most likely culprit.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a problem with the permissions. Check that the user running the server process has permission to view the file in question.